# How to save file from textarea and configure path in download code? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, file, download, path, textarea

The result after clicking the download file is folder download on my computer, but I want a specific path like "\directory\subdirectory" when I click save file.
**If javascript isn't possible how can I do it?**

```
<input id="inputFileNameToSaveAs" style="width: 400px;"></input>
<button onclick="saveTextAsFile()" style="width: 250px;">Save File</button>
function saveTextAsFile()
            {
                var textToWrite = document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value;
                var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type: 'text/plain'});
                var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById("inputFileNameToSaveAs").value;
                var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
                downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
                downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
                if (window.webkitURL !== null)
                {
                    // Chrome allows the link to be clicked
                    // without actually adding it to the DOM.
                    downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
                } else
                {
                    // Firefox requires the link to be added to the DOM
                    // before it can be clicked.
                    downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
                    downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
                    downloadLink.style.display = "none";
                    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
                }
                downloadLink.click();
            }
            function destroyClickedElement(event)
            {
                document.body.removeChild(event.target);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no possibility to do that. You can download file, but you can't write it in a specific folder. Browser is running in a sandbox for security and don't have access to whole of your computer.

You don't want some javascript on a random page you enter to mess with your computer files.

Comment: Can I use java?